# After a iPhone is stolen, can that device's iCloud backup be accessed?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I had an iPhone 4 stolen from me and there is an associated iCloud backup with tons of data I want. Is there any possible way to access this without the iPhone 4?

I also got an iPhone 5 recently but don't think the restore will work (but haven't tried).

Comment: Why wouldn't the restore work? That's one of the main benefits of iCloud – if you get a new device, just restore your iPhone backup and pick up where you left off.

Comment: I guess it will so I'll give that a shot - it's just annoying they don't let you download the backups if they already store them locally on your machine if you're not using icloud...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple doesn't expose iCloud backups directly to end users via computer or web interface, but you can restore that backup onto pretty much any other iOS device.

The new iPhone (or any iOS device for that matter) has iOS version the same or newer than the version backed up from the stolen phone. Simply erase all content on the current device (losing everything in it) and restore your old backup onto the device.

Hopefully, have not "created" much new data on your new phone and don't have to write down many new contacts or items or export any documents before you erase it. However, you could always back that device up to the same or different iCloud account or to iTunes and restore that once you've gotten your data to a more portable form.

Comment: Good advice - when I get a new phone, I typically skip the setup questions and go right to software update and get the latest version, then I erase all content and settings to get back to iCloud restore and put my backup of choice on the phone. The only reason to not upgrade would be if you like jailbreak options and want to save shsh keys and be careful about upgrading to new iOS.

Comment: Cool, but even if I did create new data on this new phone, I could force a backup - then wipe it, restore, get my data, and re-wipe the phone, right?

Comment: @inexion, something like that sounds theoretically possible. However, I'm *guessing* iCloud wouldn't *add* the new data, but instead see that there's all *new* data on the device, and then backup over the top of the old data. I couldn't find anything conclusive on that either way. That could possibly be another question. Unless you find something conclusive, I wouldn't count on that method. I would evaluate data that would be lost, then back it up an alternate way.

Comment: It'd take quite a while, but I named them differently so I could just literally take the new phone and its data, force backup, the wipe and restore with the old backup, re-wipe after pulling off everything manually using something like supercrazyawesome.com, ahhh what a pain lol

Answer (score -2):

The prior answer isn't true. Elcomsoft have a forensic app called [EPBB](http://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html) that enables you to access your data in icloud. It unfortunately costs $200!

Comment: There is also a free trial version !

Comment: It enables you to access data on the cloud provided you know the credentials. If you know the credentials and have another iOS device, why pay for something that is free?